# Rotate an image on text hover css

Tags: html, css

Now I can rotate an image on hover in css by this code:

```
.spin1 img {
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
.spin1 img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

But I want also rotate an image when hovering over text written under the image

Comment: paste your HTML as well

Comment: You might need to use javascript/jQuery for that.

Comment: share your full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that both, the *image* and its *text*, share the same *parent element*, which is the one you need to `:hover` over:

```css
.spin1 > img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.spin1:hover > img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="spin1">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="img">
  Rotate
</div>
```

Comment: The full HTML does not fit in this box, but the point is there are several such images and now they rotate all simultaneously. You are very smart coder, maybe you will see to the code in my site http://vidguard.ru/#rowspin

Comment: And without adding extra classes you can do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ytz35qdm/7/